# How to run a preloader once per session on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

I have a WordPress website with a preloader plugin installed. This shows an animation every time the home page loads. The issue is that I also have a cookie policy, so when somebody goes onto the website the animation runs the cookie policy notification appears. You then click "accept" and then the homepage reloads and the animation will run again, and runs every time the homepage is clicked. This is annoying to users so ideally I just want the preloader animation to run once on initial page load, per user session.

The CSS below will stop the page preloader from running, but of course it stops it completely, so I need some jQuery or JavaScript logic to determine if this the first session. If so run the animation otherwise do not run the animation.

I have tried the following jQuery but it hasn't worked, any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

```
.smart-page-loader, .hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var visited = sessionStorage['visited'] || false;
  if (!visited) {
    $('.smart-page-loader .hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    sessionStorage['visited'] = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Why is accepting the cookie notification reloading the page? That shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I thought it had to reload the page to install the cookies for google tracking etc, until users accept the use of cookies the website doesn't load any. The preloader animation will still run again anyway if the homepage is clicked, and that is what I am trying to avoid, thanks.

Comment: It should never reload the page. You can set the cookies client side in JS, or make an AJAX request to do it server side.

Comment: OK I guess I am wrong then about that, I thought it was supposed to do that, it's a WordPress plugin, I do not know how to set the cookies client-side in JS or AJAX, I will need to look into that issue, thanks for letting me know,